# Log4j2 not rolling over log files

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am making a game with LWJGL3 and am using log4j2 for logging. I am trying to setup my logger which works however each time the program is executed it just overwrites the lastest.log file instead of compressing it and then overwriting latest.log. I tried setting the minSize of the OnStartupTriggeringPolicy because it defaults to 1 and my file size is currently extremely small but that didn't help. Does anyone have any idea on how to get this working.

log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%level] [%t] - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" filename="log/latest.log"
            filePattern="${logPath}/%d{YYYYMMddHHmmss}.log.gz"
            append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%level] [%t] - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="8"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: What is the exact behavior you want here?  When do you want log4j2 to rollover to a new file based on size?

Comment: I would like it to rollover ever time the program starts as well as every-time the file gets to 250MB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding:

```
<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
```

Here is an example of log4j2 configuration that I currently used in my projects.

```
<RollingFile name="file-log" fileName="${log-path}/autodeployer.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/autodeployer-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50MB"/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
</RollingFile>
```

Comment: But wouldn't this _also_ rollover the log file every minute, even while the same instance of the application is running?

Comment: Just to try and get my code working I tried using the TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy in place of my OnStartup policy and it also did not seam to rollover. Could there be something wrong elsewhere?

Comment: No, this it does daily and every time the file reach 50MB then create a new file with an index at the end (-%i) but maintaining the format of current date.